# Unable to adjust the errorbar

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, error-bars

```
\resizebox{42mm}{39mm}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
        ybar,
        enlargelimits=0.05,
        legend style={at={(0.03,.88)},
        anchor=north,legend columns=-1},   
        xmajorgrids=true,
        ymajorgrids=true,
ybar interval=0.7,
legend columns=1,
        grid style=dashed,
xlabel={\Large{x}}, 
ylabel={\Large{y}},
        % symbolic x coords={20,40,60,80,100,120},
        xtick=data
    ]
        \addplot+[
            error bars/.cd,
            y fixed,
            y dir=both,
            y explicit
        ] coordinates {
          (20, 0.63) +- (0, 0.2) 
          (40, 1.07) +- (0, 0.03) 
          (60, 1.56) +- (0, 0.3)
            (80, 0.95) +- (0, 0.3)
            (100, 1.77) +- (0, 0.6)
        (120, 1.77) %+- (0, 0.6)
         };
         
        \addplot+[
            error bars/.cd,
            y fixed,
            y dir=both,
            y explicit
        ] coordinates {
            (20, 0.56)  +- (0, 0.05)
            (40, 0.95) +- (0, 0.3)
            (60, 1.77) +- (0, 0.6)
            (80, 0.95) +- (0, 0.3)
            (100, 1.77) +- (0, 0.6)
        (120, 1.77) %+- (0, 0.6)
        };
\addplot+[
            error bars/.cd,
            y fixed,
            y dir=both,
            y explicit
        ]    coordinates {
        (20,1) +- (0, 0.3)
        (40, 2) +- (0, 0.3)
        (60,3) +- (0, 0.3)
        (80, 0.95) +- (0, 0.3)
        (100, 1.77) +- (0, 0.6)
        (120, 1.77) %+- (0, 0.6)
        };
 \addplot+[
            error bars/.cd,
            y fixed,
            y dir=both,
            y explicit
        ]    coordinates {
        (20,1) +- (0, 0.3)
        (40, 2) +- (0, 0.3)
        (60,3) +- (0, 0.3)
        (80, 0.95) +- (0, 0.3)
        (100, 1.77) +- (0, 0.6)
        (120, 1.77) %+- (0, 0.6)
        };
    \addplot+[
            error bars/.cd,
            y fixed,
            y dir=both,
            y explicit
        ]    coordinates {
        (20,1) +- (0, 0.3)
        (40, 2) +- (0, 0.3)
        (60,3) +- (0, 0.3)
        (80, 0.95) +- (0, 0.3)
        (100, 1.77) +- (0, 0.6)
        (120, 1.77) %+- (0, 0.6)
        };
\legend{\large{\texttt{1}}, \large{\texttt{2}},\large{\texttt{3}}, \large{\texttt{4}}, \large{\texttt{5}}}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please EDIT your question and add to it: 1) some explanatory text, 2) a screenshot, 3) complete enough code (try to copy and compile your code; if it fails, make it more complete, until it compiles AND shows your problem AND is minimal). Thanks

Comment: Don't use `\resizebox` ... Without providing MWE, is hard to help you.